# Getting the Data in snapshot.val() but not able to treat it

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I was making an app and had to fetch data from Realtime Database. I am getting the data in *snapshot.val()* like this

```
►{xz0ezxzrpkb:{…}}
▼xz0ezxzrpkb:{blood_group:"B+",cause:"Random Cause",created_on:"08-02-2022",email:"example@gmail.com",location:"Random Location",message:"Random Message",name:"Any_Name",phone_number:"+91 *********"}
```

And Now I want to access this data. When I am trying **snapshot.val()[0].email**   and
**snapshot.val().[0].email** I am Getting

```
undefined (2)
```

So, I am working in React Native and this is the code

```
db.ref('/requests/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
       console.log(snapshot.val())
       console.log(snapshot.val()[0].email)
       console.log(snapshot.val().[0].email)
});
```

The nodes of database are as follows:
[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you show the data model of your database? I.e. add a screenhsot of the Firebase console in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the approach in Dharmaraj's answer works, I recommend using Firebase's built-in `forEach` operation, since that ensures that you process the results in the same order the database returns them:

```
db.ref('/requests/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
     console.log(childSnapshot.key)                  // "xz0ezxzrpkb"
     console.log(childSnapshot.val())                // {blood_group:"B+",cause:"Random Cause", ...
     console.log(childSnapshot.val().email)          // "example@gmail.com"
     console.log(childSnapshot.child('email').val()) // "example@gmail.com"
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. I've solved my problem with your answer :). Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot value is not an object. Try refactoring the code using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as shown below:

```
db.ref('/requests/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  Object.keys(snapshot.val()).forEach((key) => {
    const request = snapshot.val()[key];
    console.log(key, request.email)
  })
});
```